# Htmlunit, get HtmlTable rows and set them to mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, htmlunit

I used htmlunit to get htmltable rows.But I cannot set them to mysql database. My database has columns like the htmltable.How can i save current row to my database?? Can anybody help me?
Here is my code:

```
final HtmlTable table = HtmlTable)currentPage.getByXPath("//table[@role='grid']").get(0);
int i = 0;
for(final HtmlTableRow row : table.getRows()){
System.out.println(row.asText());
rows[i] = row.toString();
i++;
}
```

Comment: Why you "cannot set them to mysql database"?

Comment: All the data try to save the same cell. Htmltable has 4 column like Id,Year,Brand,Color. I want to get them with htmlunit and save them like Id,Year,Brand,Color to database. But when i get data from website, it come                                                                'Id          Year Brand Color
c80119ce 1990 Ford         Brown                                                       like tahat.How can i save to cells.